# Sharing Core data and Images to iCloud

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, icloud

I had created Entity called `**Information**` in **Coredata** model and there are three attributes in this entity as name,email and imagename respectively..

And storing all images in **document directory**.. There are two buttons called `Synch On iCloud` and `**Restore Backup**` on `Settings` page..

On `Synch On iCloud` Button, All that core data and images should go on iCloud..

How to synch all that.. I had spent 2 days research work but can't got success.. and doesn't got any guidelines for that also..

And from other device When I click on `Restore Backup`, the **coredata** model filled with that 
data that I stored on iCloud and all images also..

Please help me solve this issue..

Thanks,
Mehul.

Comment: even i had same requirement, storing the images in directory separately. Unable to manage this with icloud so saved images into coredata as it was small sizes.. if you wanna try let me know will guide you..

Comment: When you put data into the documentDirectory, you get iCloud backup for free, that's why app can be rejected if you put lot of unusefull data into it ( ~> 5M). You can get it back / send with iTunes from what i heard. I have never tried, but hope this give you clues.

Comment: have you tried - http://timroadley.com/2012/04/03/core-data-in-icloud/

Comment: i tried this : you can take image from your device and you can upload it your icloud account and you can see the images which are present in your icloud. if this is the thing you need then i can help you.

Comment: @VenkatManohar Yes dear.. I want this..

Comment: @Mehul:just look at the link i have provided. It works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go to this [link](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/add-an-icloud-photo-gallery-to-your-app-with-mticloudphotogallery-library/)

and download the code from it. It will help you. You need to set the profile entitlements and you need to set the code identity for that should be perfect according to the profile entitlements

and After downloading change this

In `MTICloudImagesController.m` file look at this statement this xib file is not declared properly

```
 MTICloudFileOpenViewController* openFile = [[MTICloudFileOpenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MTICloudFileOpenViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: if you download that file, there is a small issue in that project. u cannot open the files because in MTICloudImagesController.m file look at this statement this xib file is not declared properly MTICloudFileOpenViewController* openFile = [[MTICloudFileOpenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MTICloudFileOpenViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];